# Retrieving data from a JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to retrieve countries, states, and cities from a JSON file and put them in a selection drop-down menu as a part of the form input. But I am unable to do that. Can anyone help me where I am doing wrong?

What I want is that the user selects his country. States will dynamically be populated in the next selection input control. After selecting the state, the city list will dynamically load in the city selection input so that the user can quickly fill-up the form by choosing his location rather than typing.

```
   $url = 'jsondata/countries-states-cities.json';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $wizards  = json_decode($data, true);
    ?>
    <form>
        <select name="Color">
            <?php foreach ($wizards as $wizard) {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $wizard['iso2']; ?>"><?php echo $wizard['iso2']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <select name="Color">
            <?php foreach ($wizards as $wizard) {?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $wizard['states']; ?>"><?php echo $wizard['states']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
<select name="Color">
        <?php foreach ($wizards as $wizard) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $wizard['states'][city]; ?>"><?php echo $wizard['states'][city]; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

And the JSON File data is contained in an associative array format.

```
[
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "iso3": "AFG",
        "iso2": "AF",
        "phone_code": "93",
        "capital": "Kabul",
        "currency": "AFN",
        "states": {
            "Badakhshan": [
                "Ashkāsham",
                "Fayzabad",
                "Jurm",
                "Khandūd",
                "Rāghistān",
                "Wākhān"
            ],
            "Badghis": [
                "Ghormach",
                "Qala i Naw"
            ],
            "Baghlan": [
                "Ḩukūmatī Dahanah-ye Ghōrī",
                "Baghlān",
                "Nahrīn",
                "Pul-e Khumrī"
            ],
            "Balkh": [
                "Balkh",
                "Dowlatābād",
                "Khulm",
                "Lab-Sar",
                "Mazār-e Sharīf",
                "Qarchī Gak"
            ],
            "Bamyan": [
                "Bāmyān",
                "Panjāb"
            ],
            "Daykundi": [
                "Nīlī"
            ],
            "Farah": [
                "Farah"
            ],
            "Faryab": [
                "Andkhōy",
                "Maymana"
            ],
            "Ghazni": [
                "Ghazni"
            ],
            "Ghōr": [
                "Fayrōz Kōh",
                "Shahrak"
            ],
            "Helmand": [
                "‘Alāqahdārī Dīshū",
                "Gereshk",
                "Lashkar Gāh",
                "Markaz-e Ḩukūmat-e Darwēshān",
                "Sangīn"
            ],
            "Herat": [
                "Chahār Burj",
                "Ghōriyān",
                "Herāt",
                "Kafir Qala",
                "Karukh",
                "Kuhsān",
                "Kushk",
                "Qarah Bāgh",
                "Shīnḏanḏ",
                "Tīr Pul",
                "Zindah Jān"
            ],
            "Jowzjan": [
                "Āqchah",
                "Darzāb",
                "Qarqīn",
                "Shibirghān"
            ],
            "Kabul": [
                "Kabul",
                "Mīr Bachah Kōṯ",
                "Paghmān"
            ],
            "Kandahar": [
                "Kandahār"
            ],
            "Kapisa": [
                "Sidqābād"
            ],
            "Khost": [
                "Khōst"
            ],
            "Kunar": [
                "Asadābād",
                "Āsmār"
            ],
            "Kunduz Province": [
                "Dasht-e Archī",
                "Imām Şāḩib",
                "Khanabad",
                "Kunduz",
                "Qarāwul"
            ],
            "Laghman": [
                "Mehtar Lām"
            ],
            "Logar": [
                "Ḩukūmatī Azrah",
                "Baraki Barak",
                "Pul-e ‘Alam"
            ],
            "Nangarhar": [
                "Bāsawul",
                "Jalālābād",
                "Markaz-e Woluswalī-ye Āchīn"
            ],
            "Nimruz": [
                "Khāsh",
                "Mīrābād",
                "Rūdbār",
                "Zaranj"
            ],
            "Nuristan": [
                "Pārūn"
            ],
            "Paktia": [
                "Gardez"
            ],
            "Paktika": [
                "Saṟōbī",
                "Zaṟah Sharan",
                "Zarghūn Shahr"
            ],
            "Panjshir": [
                "Bāzārak"
            ],
            "Parwan": [
                "Charikar",
                "Jabal os Saraj"
            ],
            "Samangan": [
                "Aībak"
            ],
            "Sar-e Pol": [
                "Chīras",
                "Larkird",
                "Qal‘ah-ye Shahr",
                "Sang-e Chārak",
                "Sar-e Pul",
                "Tagāw-Bāy",
                "Tukzār"
            ],
            "Takhar": [
                "Ārt Khwājah",
                "Taloqan"
            ],
            "Urozgan": [
                "Tarinkot",
                "Uruzgān"
            ],
            "Zabul": [
                "Qalāt"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Aland Islands",
        "iso3": "ALA",
        "iso2": "AX",
        "phone_code": "+358-18",
        "capital": "Mariehamn",
        "currency": "EUR"
    },
{
        "id": 231,
        "name": "United Arab Emirates",
        "iso3": "ARE",
        "iso2": "AE",
        "phone_code": "971",
        "capital": "Abu Dhabi",
        "currency": "AED",
        "states": {
            "Abu Dhabi Emirate": [
                "Abu Dhabi Island and Internal Islands City",
                "Abu Dhabi Municipality",
                "Al Ain City",
                "Al Ain Municipality",
                "Al Dhafra",
                "Al Shamkhah City",
                "Ar Ruways",
                "Bani Yas City",
                "Khalifah A City",
                "Musaffah",
                "Muzayri‘",
                "Zayed City"
            ],
            "Ajman Emirate": [
                "Ajman",
                "Ajman City",
                "Manama",
                "Masfout"
            ],
            "Dubai": [
                "Dubai"
            ],
            "Fujairah": [
                "Al Fujairah City",
                "Al Fujairah Municipality",
                "Dibba Al Fujairah Municipality",
                "Dibba Al-Fujairah",
                "Dibba Al-Hisn",
                "Reef Al Fujairah City"
            ],
            "Ras al-Khaimah": [
                "Ras Al Khaimah",
                "Ras Al Khaimah City"
            ],
            "Sharjah Emirate": [
                "Adh Dhayd",
                "Al Batayih",
                "Al Hamriyah",
                "Al Madam",
                "Dhaid",
                "Dibba Al Hesn",
                "Kalba",
                "Khawr Fakkān",
                "Khor Fakkan",
                "Milehah",
                "Murbaḩ",
                "Sharjah"
            ],
            "Umm al-Quwain": [
                "Umm AL Quwain",
                "Umm Al Quwain City"
            ]
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: For the kind of autoload functionality you seek, you will have to turn to JavaScript or use jQuery for that. Dynamic autoloading content on a webpage can be done through a front-end scripting language like JS, not through a backend server-side scripting language like PHP.

Comment: Think of PHP as something which processes things, adds or modifies content and then sends the result to the browser. For modifying a page through PHP, you will have to reload the page. But JS can do it on the fly. But you can use PHP through AJAX. So, look into that.

Comment: @AkashDas I will use JavaScript Select2 Library But actually data in not showing in selection input from backend. I think i did something in code.

Comment: i think you see this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194476/show-data-in-database-after-select-an-input-select/58246413#58246413